# Accessing the XBOX One Controller with C# via Bluetooth

Tags: c#, bluetooth, sharpdx, gamepad, xbox-one

I have an app in C# that uses SharpDX to handle a Xbox one controller via USB.

I want the app take advantage of the Xbox one controller Bluetooth capabilities, but I can't communicate with it.

How can I access the xbox one controller via bluetooth with C#?

I hope someone can guide me on the right path. I don't have any experience accessing Bluetooth devices with C#.

Comment: Wheres your c# code?

Comment: I don't have any code to handle the xbox one control via Bluetooth

Comment: Have a look [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Accessing-the-XBOX-One-Controller-with-C-and-making-it-Accessible-too)

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, but that link explains how to use the xbox one controller with USB cable, I need to access the controller with bluetooth.